# How to get the Cookies from listeners?

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, servlet-listeners

I made an app and I want to get cookies as soon as there is new session. I tried it with the session listener but didn't work. I tried it with the request listener but got a null in cookies array.
this is the code from request listener and it gets me null every time

```
public void requestInitialized(ServletRequestEvent sre) {
    
    HttpServletRequest req=(HttpServletRequest)sre.getServletRequest();
    if(req.getSession().isNew())
    {
        Cookie c[]=req.getCookies();
        try
        {
            for (Cookie co:c)
            {
                System.out.println(co.getName());
                System.out.println(co.getValue());
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("error: "+ e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please extend the question with the examples of the code which you tried?

Comment: @IllyaKysil I put it , any help

Comment: Could you please confirm that cookies were actually sent by the client? HttpServletRequest#getCookies() returns null if there are no cookies in the request - https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getCookies()

Comment: I opened the cookies of the browser and they are already there and I tried the code in the filter and it worked

Answer (score 0):

The `HttpServletRequest.getCookies()` returns cookies provided in the request - as described in the [HttpServletRequest's javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getCookies()).

When servlet container creates a new session, it usually means that either no cookies were provided (session is unknown) or there was a session cookie, but the session itself has been expired.

Please check section 7.1 Session Tracking Mechanisms of the [Java™ Servlet Specification](https://javaee.github.io/servlet-spec/downloads/servlet-4.0/servlet-4_0_FINAL.pdf) for the complete explanation of the **standard** session semantics and lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out , the problem was with chrome. it consider the cookie as session cookie until I added header "Expires" to the response